# If an ordinary six-sided die is thrown four times, find the probability of obtaining two even numbers and two odd numbers.

Tags: probability

An ordinary die is has six faces numbered from 1 to 6. If an ordinary die is thrown four times, find the probability of obtaining two even numbers and two odd numbers.

Comment: Any thoughts?  Since Even/odd are equal probability you can just think of this as $4$ coin tosses out of which you want two Heads.  If all else fails, enumeration is easy.

Comment: $\binom42\cdot\left(\frac36\right)^{2}\cdot\left(1-\frac36\right)^{4-2}$

Answer (score 1):

There are two outcomes with equal probability, so you want to divide *combination* $\binom{4}{2}=6$ (these are the cases you want) to the number of all possible outcomes (even or odd) which is $2^4$. So 6/16 should be the answer.